# Spring Tool Suite: error to update to version 3.9.0

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm updating Spring Tool Suite to version 3.9.0 from Version: 3.8.4.RELEASE Build Id: 201703310825 Platform: Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

But I've this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.core,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.livegraph,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.reloading,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.ui,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,io.projectreactor.reactor-core,3.0.7.201706071909-RELEASE
```

...

Please, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like p2 is using some stale or corrupted cache data. To fix this you can go to the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Udpate Sites` and press `Reload` on the STS update site.

If that doesn't help, you can also try to remove that update site, restart STS, and add that update site back to the list. This causes the internal caches to be wiped out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing done. Please, read my answer (I can't write long details in this comment). Thanks

Comment: @Martin Lippert, I tried both "Reload" and removing/adding back the https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.11 URL in STS 3.9.8 and this does not help for "No Repository Found" for a number of installed packages, which will abort the update.

Comment: Make sure to restart STS after removing the update sites and before adding them back. It also depends on the exact artifacts that gets reported as not found. Also make sure you use the https variant of the update site URL. If all that doesn't help, I would recommend to file an issue to discuss more details and to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

Today STS does not find any update! Very strange...

This is my list of Available Update Sites.

```
<bookmarks>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/2.x" selected="true" name="Buildship"/>
   <site url="http://jasperstudio.sourceforge.net/updates/" selected="true" name="Jaspersoft Studio Update Site"/>
   <site url="https://dl.bintray.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-eclipse-site/" selected="true" name="MapStruct Eclipse repository"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon" selected="true" name="Neon"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000" selected="true" name="Neon"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20160221192158/repository/" selected="true" name="Orbit-R20160221192158"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project repository"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/" selected="true" name="Xtext All In One (Releases)"/>
   <site url="http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/xpand/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.23" selected="false" name=""/>
   <site url="http://jasperstudio.sf.net/updates" selected="false" name=""/>
</bookmarks>
```

I tried do Reload each site but nothing happenend.

But, maybe I haven't the site in the list for STS updates ?

Comment: Looks like you don't have the STS update site in your preferences, so no wonder that it doesn't find any updates... :-) Please add: http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.6/